# Android Studio Firebase Cloud Messaging Not Working?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an e-commerce application in which when user orders places an order, the seller should receive a notification of new order. I am able to send notifications as it shows a toast message of "Response" but no notification is received on the seller part. I checked the code multiple times but I am still unable to find out where I am making the mistake. Here is my code

```js
public class MyFirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "MY_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID";
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        String notificationType = remoteMessage.getData().get("notificationType");

        if (notificationType.equals("NewOrder")){
            String buyerUid = remoteMessage.getData().get("buyerUid");
            String sellerUid = remoteMessage.getData().get("sellerUid");
            String orderId = remoteMessage.getData().get("orderId");
            String notificationTitle = remoteMessage.getData().get("notificationTitle");
            String notificationMessage = remoteMessage.getData().get("notificationMessage");

            if (firebaseUser != null && firebaseAuth.getUid().equals(sellerUid)){
                showNotification(orderId,sellerUid,buyerUid,notificationTitle,notificationMessage,notificationType);
            }

        }

        if (notificationType.equals("OrderStatusChanged")){
            String buyerUid = remoteMessage.getData().get("buyerUid");
            String sellerUid = remoteMessage.getData().get("sellerUid");
            String orderId = remoteMessage.getData().get("orderId");
            String notificationTitle = remoteMessage.getData().get("notificationTitle");
            String notificationMessage = remoteMessage.getData().get("notificationMessage");

            if (firebaseUser != null && firebaseAuth.getUid().equals(buyerUid)){
                showNotification(orderId,sellerUid,buyerUid,notificationTitle,notificationMessage,notificationType);

            }
        }
    }

    private void showNotification(String orderId,String sellerUid,String buyerUid,String notificationTitle,String notificationDescription,String notificationType){
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int notificationID = new Random().nextInt(3000);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            setUpNotificationChannel(notificationManager);
        }
        Intent intent = null;
        if (notificationType.equals("NewOrder")){
            intent = new Intent(this,ShopOrderDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("orderId",orderId);
            intent.putExtra("orderBy",buyerUid);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        } else if (notificationType.equals("OrderStatusChanged")){
            intent = new Intent(this,UserOrderDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("orderId",orderId);
            intent.putExtra("orderTo",sellerUid);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        }

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.indianflag);

        //notification sound
        Uri notificationSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.indianflag)
        .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
        .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
        .setContentText(notificationDescription)
        .setSound(notificationSoundUri)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        //show notification
        notificationManager.notify(notificationID,notificationBuilder.build());

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void setUpNotificationChannel(NotificationManager notificationManager) {
        CharSequence channelName = "Some sample text";
        String channelDescription = "Channel Description Here";
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,channelName,NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationChannel.setDescription(channelDescription);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        if (notificationManager != null){
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
private void prepareNotification(String orderId){
        String NOTIFICATION_TOPIC = "/topics/"+ Constants.FCM_TOPIC;
        String NOTIFICATION_TITLE = "New Order "+orderId;
        String NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE = "You have a new order";
        String NOTIFICATION_TYPE = "NewOrder";

        JSONObject notificationJo = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject notificationBodyJo = new JSONObject();

        Log.d("userId",mAuth.getUid());
        Log.d("shopId",shopId);
        Log.d("orderId",orderId);

        try{
            notificationBodyJo.put("notificationType",NOTIFICATION_TYPE);
            notificationBodyJo.put("buyerUid",mAuth.getUid());
            notificationBodyJo.put("sellerUid",shopId);
            notificationBodyJo.put("orderId",orderId);
            notificationBodyJo.put("notificationTitle",NOTIFICATION_TITLE);
            notificationBodyJo.put("notificationMessage",NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);

            notificationJo.put("to",NOTIFICATION_TOPIC);
            notificationJo.put("data",notificationBodyJo);

        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(ProceedToCheckoutActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        sendFCMNotification(notificationJo,orderId);
    }

    private void sendFCMNotification(JSONObject notificationJo, String timeStamp1) {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", notificationJo, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Toast.makeText(ProceedToCheckoutActivity.this, "Response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProceedToCheckoutActivity.this,UserOrderDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("shopID",shopId);
                intent.putExtra("orderId",timeStamp1);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Error Here",error.toString());
                Toast.makeText(ProceedToCheckoutActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProceedToCheckoutActivity.this,UserOrderDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("shopID",shopId);
                intent.putExtra("orderId",timeStamp1);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }){


            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Content-Type","application/json");
                headers.put("Authorization","key="+Constants.FCM_KEY);
                return headers;
            }
        };

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonObjectRequest);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use retrofit or volley to send notifications to second user.

Link: [sending fcm push notifications using retrofit library in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117563/sending-fcm-push-notifications-using-retrofit-library-in-android?rq=1)

Module:app dependencies

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'
```

ApiClient

```
public class ApiClient {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

ApiInterface

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @Headers({"Authorization: key=" + ConstantKey.SERVER_KEY, "Content-Type:application/json"})
    @POST("fcm/send")
    Call<ResponseBody> sendNotification(@Body RootModel root);
}
```

RootModel

```
public class RootModel {

    @SerializedName("to") //  "to" changed to token
    private String token;

    @SerializedName("notification")
    private NotificationModel notification;

    @SerializedName("data")
    private DataModel data;

    public RootModel(String token, NotificationModel notification, DataModel data) {
        this.token = token;
        this.notification = notification;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public NotificationModel getNotification() {
        return notification;
    }

    public void setNotification(NotificationModel notification) {
        this.notification = notification;
    }

    public DataModel getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(DataModel data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

NotificationModel

```
public class NotificationModel {

    private String title;
    private String body;

    public NotificationModel(String title, String body) {
        this.title = title;
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

DataModel

```
public class DataModel {

    private String name;
    private String age;

    public DataModel(String name, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

Send notification by using this method

```
private void sendNotificationToUser(String token) {
    RootModel rootModel = new RootModel(token, new NotificationModel("Title", "Body"), new DataModel("Name", "30"));

    ApiInterface apiService =  ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    retrofit2.Call<ResponseBody> responseBodyCall = apiService.sendNotification(rootModel);

    responseBodyCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Successfully notification send by using retrofit.");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```